# How do I make part of my place holder bold(only the dollar symbol)

Tags: html, css

How do I make part of my place holder bold(only the dollar symbol).

I'm trying to put two inputs "$min" "$max" with the $ bold but I don't know how I can add that in a place holder

```
<li><a><input type="text" name="text" placeholder="$min"><input type="text" name="text" placeholder="$max"></a></li>
```

Comment: Links cannot contain inputs, it's invalid HTML

Comment: use pseudoelements like logically `::placeholder::first-letter` but browsers don't support it.... others ways are `::-webkit-input-placeholder::first-letter` `::-moz-placeholder::first-letter` `:-ms-input-placeholder:first-letter` also **not sopported** if there is `::first-letter` in the end of selector